# Polygons from Adobe Acrobat PDF to Arc

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, polygon, pdf

I am tracing building plans in adobe acrobat. There may be a time in the future I will be asked to take the polygons and overlay them in a GIS for a borough-wide map. Are there any steps I can take from the start in preparation for such a task.

The image below is a very simple plan I have traced. Many others are far more complex, and the colour scheme (and label within polygon) are important information I would like to retain.

[image]

Comment: Have you considered saving your pdfs as jp2 or tif files in Acrobat, georeferencing them in ArcGIS, and then creating features with a pre-set symbology, assuming you have ArcGIS 10x.  In some cases to cut down on digitizing, you might be able to use arcscan to create lines from the rasterized drawings, then use the spatial adjustment tools to "georeference" them and then attribute them to match your symbology.

Comment: I have tried the arcscan in the past but quite a few of the PDF scans are of poor quality so the automatic vectorisation was bad. The way I georeferenced the PDFs when trying the aforementioned method was in mapinfo, selecting 3 points that aligned to the base map. If there was a quicker way of importing (say, select a corner on the PDF and give it a coordinate value so it will place quicker in mapinfo/arc) then that would be good.